# How to make sure a focus on single textboxt after every possible user action?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function to make cursor focus to a textbox.

```
function getfocus(){
    
    var focusbox;
    
    focusbox = document.getElementById("i_focushere");
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        focusbox.focus();
    }, 1);
}
```

I call this function on some event like `change` and `click`. Something like this.

```
//FORCE FOCUS SELECT
$(document).on('change','select', function(e){
    getfocus();
});

//FORCE FOCUS BUTTON
$(document).on('click','button', function(e){
    getfocus();
});
```

Is that enough to make sure focus after every possible user action. Users action is limited to a page only though. Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: you can also use : 
<input onblur="this.focus()" autofocus />

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan if I use blur, I cannot click on any select